# Why is this Rails view helper logic failing in one instance but functioning in another?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, parameter-passing

I am confused by the handling of parameters and results passed to and from my Rails view helper:

```
module CasesHelper
    def case_owned(owner,cur_usr)       
        return false if (owner.nil?)
        return false if (cur_usr.nil?)
        x = User.find(cur_usr)
        y = User.find(owner)  

        ## this does not returns 'true' 
        ## when expected 
        ## return true if (owner == cur_usr)

        return true if (x == y)     #<<<< This line works
        return false
    end
end
```

This is the view code:

```
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', c %></td>
    <td><%= (link_to 'Edit', edit_case_path(c)) if case_owned(c.user_id,current_user) %></td>
    <td><%= (link_to 'Destroy', c, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' })  if case_owned(c.user_id,current_user) %></td>
```

How can the working code work and the commented-out line not?  Why is the User.find() call necessary to ensure equality.  And, how can:

```
   User.find(cur_usr) == User.find(owner)
```

...evaluate to `true`

when:

```
   cur_usr == owner
```

... evaluates to `false`

I am using the Devise gem for authentication and it is supplying the current_user method.  I initially coded the above with the "cur_usr == owner" line, but realized using the User.find() approach worked.  It's confusing to me how the parameters passed into find() can be considered unequal, but the objects (records) that are returned get evaluated as equal.  What am I missing here?

Please try to direct your comments towards how Ruby handles passing objects as parameters or how the Rails naming convention is 'helping' here.  My thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`current_user` normally returns a `User` instance, which works fine if you run it through `User.find(cur_user)` (it returns the same user). However, your first argument is an id (`c.user_id` in the view). You could do `owner == cur_user.id`.

If you always expect an ID in the method, you should probably name the variable `owner_id`.

Comment: I tried using the calling args of case.user_id and current_user_id, but current_user_id threw an error.  I then tried current_user.id as a calling arg, but that also threw an error.  I do understand how passing an instance of User and a user_id to User.find() can return the same result.  Thanks for pointing out the important difference in the object types received by case_owned.

Comment: Yes.  Owner_id would be better.  I just tried "return true if (owner == cur_usr.id)" and it works fine.  Thanks!  Much faster than doing the two table queries each time.  Still not sure why current_user.id wouldn't work as a calling arg from within the view.